# Trouble Converting Value to Decimal JAVA (Android)

Tags: java, android, decimal

I am currently working on an app for Android.  In this app, I need to convert a calculated number to a percentage.  The original number (tipTotal) is calculated correctly, but when I try to convert to decimal by dividing by 100 (tipPercentage), tipPercentage is always 0.0.

I have confirmed that tipTotal is correct and what I expect.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            int tipTotal = 0;
            float totalBill = 0;
            float tipPercentage = 0;                
            String time, attitude, refills, clearing, accuracy, bill;

            time = timeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            attitude = attitudeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            refills = refillsSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            clearing = clearingSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            accuracy = accuracySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            bill = txtBill.getText().toString();

            tipTotal = Integer.parseInt(time)+Integer.parseInt(attitude)+Integer.parseInt(refills)+Integer.parseInt(clearing)+Integer.parseInt(accuracy);

            tipPercentage = tipTotal / 100;

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(tipPercentage), duration);
            toast.show();

        }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
tipPercentage = ((float)tipTotal)/ 100f;
```

The problem could be that `tipTotal / 100` is doing an integer division... which has no decimal part, and which is less than 1. That's how integer divisions works... for instance: `10/6 = 1`. On the other hand `10f/6f=1.6666`.

Comment: Hi guys you were correct, I made a total noob mistake! I should have known better. Thanks!

Comment: But what if the user enters either "25.6" or "0.256" or ".256" and you want it to be "0.256"?

Answer (score 0):

I'll second Cristian's reply, it almost certainly is because `tipTotal / 100` is an integer division, which in your case seems to be returning `int 0` which is then type cast to `float 0.0`

So one way to resolve this would be to take Cristian's suggestion and force division of two floats.

The other option is to declare `tipTotal` as `float tipTotal = 0;` in which case the division would proceed as per your expectation since `100` will be automatically promoted to float.

EDIT: To gain a better understanding check out http://mindprod.com/jgloss/division.html